# How to Connect Sqlite from EF Designer from Database

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2015

I've installed SQLite version `1.0.99` and my connection is succeeded when i'm connecting with database from EF designer wizard. but in next step to generate model it shows error as shown in image. how i can I resolve it?

[image]

My project version is `4.5.1.` Visual studio 2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by your error image, it looks like you have a version conflict; 1.0.98 vs 1.0.99. I would update your SQLite version to match using NuGet or the Package Manager console and try again.

Comment: Which version i should install? for dataset it works fine, but for entity framwork it shows that erro. should i try sqlite version 1.0.98?

Comment: Misread your error. According to the error, the version you have installed in Visual Studio is 1.0.99, but on your machine (in your Global Assembly Cache) is version 1.0.98. So one option would be to downgrade your solution to 1.0.98. Other solution is to upgrade your local version to 1.0.99 (preferred).

Comment: how i can upgrade my local version ?

Comment: Easiest way would be to use the 1.0.99.0 System.Data.SQLite setup provided [here](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki) which should do it automatically. If that does not update your GAC, you can update the GAC manually by downloading the precompiled binaries from that same link and following [this guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560649.aspx).